# CSS: Stylable Underline at Baseline

Tags: html, css, text, underline

How can I add an underline to an inline-element in CSS, that is (1.) "stylable" and (2.) at the baseline (unlike solutions using only border-bottom or box-shadow)?

This is for a responsive layout, so the underline has to be able to reach over multiple lines. Also, it cannot displace any other (not underlines) text that might be inline with the link.

This is a mock-up to demonstrate the desired effect.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would take a look at this: https://css-tricks.com/styling-underlines-web/.

Comment: @DerekBrown Thanks for the comment! The article looks promising.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For everyone interested, this is the solution I came up with. It only works on a solid background.

```
background: linear-gradient(white, white), linear-gradient(blue, blue);
background-position: 0px calc(1em + 5px), 0px 1em;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
color: black;
background-color: white;
```

Comment: This looks specific to the font's size and family you're using. Each time you change your font, you'll have to revisit this.

Comment: Since I am using em as the unit it works fairly well even when different font sizes are used.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd want to use a pseudo element to style your underline. I threw a simple animation too on hover to showcase its flexibility.

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
}

h1::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 5px;
  z-index: -1;
  background: aqua;
  height: 2px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: width 0.3s;
}

h1:hover::before {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a styleable baseline</h1>
```

Comment: Baseline refers to the horizontal rule where the base of letters rest. In your example, the underline should be higher, such that the tail of the lower-case `y` will be positioned below that line.

Comment: @LucasMorgan you can easily add a negative value to the bottom element. I don't think if you can find a one size fits all for having consistent margins with font families, but what I recommend is using a sass variable as a constant when defining your margins. When you change font families just change the global variable.

Comment: Why are you telling me this? I am articulating what a font's baseline is and how this answer misleads that definition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you aren't able to use border-bottom but try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
    </style>
    <body>
        <a><u>LINK OVER </u><br><u>MULTIPLE</u> LINES</a><br><br>
        <a><span style="border-bottom: blue solid 3px;">LINK OVER 
<br>MULTIPLE</span> LINES</a><br><br>
      <a><span style="text-decoration: underline;  text-decoration-color: 
blue;">LINK OVER<br>MULTIPLE </span> LINES</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not change the thickness of the line. Also, text-decoration-color is not a cross-browser solution.